# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0に静的IPを指定すると、 名前解決ができない

Tags: centos, vmware

CentOS6.5(仮想環境)を構築して、最初のDHCPの段階では、
下記のコマンド(GIPを調べるコマンド)がうまくいってました。

```
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
HWADDR="00:0C:29:18:06:BE"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"

[root@localhost ~]# curl http://httpbin.org/ip
{
  "origin": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
}
```

ところが/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0に静的IPを指定した場合に、
下記のように表示されてしまいます。

```
[root@localhost ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR="00:0C:29:18:06:BE"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
IPADDR=192.168.1.40

[root@localhost network-scripts]# curl http://httpbin.org/ip
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'httpbin.org'
```

物理マシン(Windowsに仮想環境をたてている)のIPは192.168.1.6で同一のネットワーク、なおping送信の返却を正常におこなわれただしく疎通がとれております。

どのようなことが考えられるかご教授ねがえますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あまりcurlは日頃使ってませんが、こういうときに良くやるのがデバッグ情報を出してみることかなと。--verbose オプションというのがあるらしいですね。[curl.1 man ページ](http://www.hcn.zaq.ne.jp/___/unix/curl_manpage.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DHCPによって参照先DNSサーバが自動で設定されていたものが、DHCPを止めたことで設定されず名前解決が出来ていないのでしょう。

/etc/resolv.confにDNSサーバのIPアドレス(一般的な家庭の環境であればルータのIPアドレスか、プロバイダのDNSサーバのIPアドレス)を記載してください

Comment: NetworkManager をお使いの場合は、/etc/resolv.conf が書き換えられてしまいますので、ifcfg-eth0 に「PEERDNS=no」として書き換えしないようにするか、「DNS1=IPアドレス」と DNSサーバーを指定するといいと思います。

Comment: @suzukisさん、@Taichiさん
アドバイスありがとうございます。ifcfg-eth0にDNS1=192.168.1.1(これが今のデフォルトゲートウェイになっている)ので、変更したところ、結果がかわりました。

しかし、依然としてグローバルＩＰの情報が取得できません。

[root@localhost etc]# curl http://httpbin.org/ip
curl: (7) Failed to connect to XX.XXX.XXX.XXX: ネットワークに届きません
[root@localhost etc]#
これはどのようなことが考えられるでしょうか。質問ばかりですみません。

Comment: デフォルトゲートウェイが設定されていないのではないでしょうか。
ifcfg-eth0 に「GATEWAY=192.168.1.1」を設定してみてください。

Comment: @Taichiさん
ifcfg-eth0 に「GATEWAY=192.168.1.1」を設定したら、解決できました！ありがとうございます！